# Conceptual meaning of frame of reference for kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, inertial-frames, relative-motion

what does the statement

> **The speed, and thus the kinetic energy of a single object is frame-dependent (relative)**

even mean? does the impact of a collision of moving bodies and henceforth transfer of kinetic energy change depending on frame of reference?
for example, A and B moving are moving with 10m/s and 8m/s velocities towards each other. If they were to collide, would a person inside B feel the collision was much more than what an independent observer see. Would deformation of object due to collision(lets say it happens) seem much greater to a person inside B than an outside observer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty strange concept, I don't blame you for feeling confused!

To use your example of two objects approaching each other at 8 and 10m/s respectively, you might be able to see that if you were sitting in object A's frame of reference (like an ant sitting on the surface of a ball), object A wouldn't be moving at all, and object B would appear to be moving towards you at 18m/s. It would have an inordinately high amount of kinetic (due to the square in 1/2mv^2) when compared to the 8&10m/s frame of reference you proposed.

This is even stranger to consider when taking into account conservation of energy. Your motion as an observer will mean that you may disagree with another observer an as to the total energy in a system. However, there is still no disagreement as to the outcome of a collision: everyone involved will know how deformed the object is. This is because the extra energy associated with a given frame of reference is in a certain sense imbedded into the center of mass of that system. You can imagine putting an opaque covering around the two objects colliding, and from your perspective this would only look like some object moving through space at constant speed. Any collisions/interactions internal to the covering cannot affect the motion of the system as a whole.

This means that this extra energy you observe has no physical effects on the interactions in the system.

Comment: does that mean for any accurate prediction using energy you would have to be independent of the system you are predicting outcome of? If yes, then are any prediction we ever make related to astrophysics even true?

Comment: There's a sense in which all physical predictions are inaccurate, because they are limited by our ability to measure the conditions of the system, and our ability to model that system accurately (both of which will likely have some inevitable rounding/approximation). However, from an astrophysics perspective, there is nothing limiting about observing a system of which you are a member. You can always do a coordinate transformation and picture the system from the POV of someone fixed to the distant stars, if need be.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate what observers in different frame observe assume the initial velocity of $A$ to be $10\,\rm m/s$ to the right and that of $B$ to be $8\,\rm m/s$ to the left with the right being the positive direction.
Furthermore assume that $A$ and $B$ each have a mass of $1\,\rm kg$ and after collision they stick together.

The first thing to note is that no frame of reference has been stated, so assume that the velocities are relative to the ground (G).

Given such a problem one would consider the system to be $A$ and $B$ and make an assumption that there are no external forces acting hence linear momentum is conserved, ie $1\times 10+ 1\times (-8) = 2 \times v_{\rm AB,G}$ where $v_{\rm AB,G}$ is the velocity of $A$ and $B$ after collision and hence $v_{\rm AB,G}=1\,\rm m/s$ (to the right).
The loss of kinetic energy in the ground frame is $\frac12 \times 10^2+\frac 12 \times 8^2-\frac 12\times 2 \times 1^2 = 81\,\rm J.$

Now consider a reference frame (A) moving to the right at $10\,\rm m/s$.
Applying conservation of momentum $1\times 0+ 1\times (-18) = 2 \times v_{\rm AB,A}$ where $v_{\rm AB,A}$ is the velocity of $A$ and $B$ after collision and hence $v_{\rm AB,A}=9\,\rm m/s$ (to the left).
The loss of kinetic energy in frame A is $\frac12 \times 0^2+\frac 12 \times (-18)^2-\frac 12\times 2 \times (-9)^2 = 81\,\rm J$ exactly the same as when measurements are made in the ground frame.

To understand why this equality has to be so, go back to the system consisting of $A$ and $B$ with no external forces acting.
This means that the velocity of the centre of mass of the system is unchanged from before to after the collision.

In whichever frame the initial readings of velocity were taken, in the frame of the centre of mass of the system, A is moving to the right at $9\,\rm m/s$ and $B$ is moving to the left at $9\,\rm m/s$, ie the total linear momentum is zero and after the collision AB is not moving, thus the loss of kinetic energy in the CoM frame is $\frac12 \times 9^2+\frac 12 \times 9^2-0 = 81\,\rm J.$

So the first example can be thought of as observing events whilst moving relative to the centre of mass frame at $1\,\rm m/s$ to the right and the second example can be thought of as observing events whilst moving relative to the centre of mass frame at $10\,\rm m/s$ to the right, neither motions having any effect on what actually happens in terms of energy loss as a result of the collision.

*If they were to collide, would a person inside B feel the collision was much more than what an independent observer see. Would deformation of object due to collision(lets say it happens) seem much greater to a person inside B than an outside observer?* **No**.

Answer (score 0):

> does the impact of a collision of moving bodies and henceforth
> transfer of kinetic energy change depending on frame of reference?

No.

Let A and B be two cars in a collision. It is obvious that the result of a collision between the cars is not different in different reference frames (Just ask anyone injured in the collision!). That's because the result of a collision between the cars depends on the *closing speed* of the cars, not on the velocity of the individual cars which is frame dependent. The closing speed is the same for all non-relativistic reference frames.

Hope this helps.